# Embedded structs in aerospike-go library unexpected behaviour

Tags: database, go, marshalling, aerospike, nosql

**Aerospike Go client**

### Problem

Need to add set of common fields to all the sets ,ie CreatedAt,UpdtedAt,DeletedAt etc. For the same I have created a struct and embed that with all the set structs. I need the Fields of the common structure saved in the set as fields of the given record

### Sample Code

```
type Table struct {
   CreatedAt time.Time
   UpdatedAt time.Time
   DeletedAt time.Time
}


type Account struct {
   Table
   Name string
   Status bool
   .....
}
```

For the above mentioned struct `Account`.I expect the record stored with bin names

```
CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,DeletedAt,Name,Status.....
```

But when the records are stored  bin names are

```
Table,Name,Status...
```

Where `Table` would be a map with key values

Is it possible to achieve the expected behaviour ? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Struct embedding **embeds methods and doesn't reflect attributes**. Attributes of inner type are accessible thorough outer type but don't exist among attributes of outer type. So defining attribute of type `Table` you literally define attribute of type `Table` not reflect all attributes of type `Table` to type `Account`.

Try to print your `Account` struct - [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jWdGp9Q9D7).

Comment: This is very specific to aerospike.Hiw they Marshall object